# Make the link visible when hovering a non-link element

Tags: javascript, html, css

You know when you hover a < a> element and the link appears in the bottom left corner of the browser?
Is it possible to do it with another tag?

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can put an `<a>` element over/around another element and 'disable' the link (onclick) using javascript to achieve a similar result:

```
<a href="//Message in the status bar!" onclick="return false">
    <div>
         This div shows something in the status bar 
         but is actually surrounded by a disabled link
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Good answer, but the status bar will look something like this:  "http://message%20in%20the%20status%20bar%21"  (See https://jsfiddle.net/6gexggqa/1)  To make it more meaningful, you could use `href="about:Message...`.  (See https://jsfiddle.net/6gexggqa/)

Comment: @RickHitchcock Thank you :)! That's a good idea!

Comment: Problem is that it has some incomprehensible css that nobody wants to mess with, and putting anything else will break the responsiveness.

Comment: I prefer using a hash symbol in front of the message, like: `href="#Message in status bar`. This way, even if javascript is disabled (or not executing due to an error), clicking will not navigate to another page, but merely update the url in the address bar.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Setting the status bar manually has been disabled in modern browsers for security reasons.  A malicious site developer could make the status bar display a different URL than the one they would be taken to on a link.

The Javascript property used to work like this:

```
window.status = "Status bar text";
```

This no longer does anything at all by default on any current browser.

Comment: create a example for this

Comment: How can one create an example of something that's can't be done?

Comment: I'd argue that I did create an example.  And if anyone were to run that in Netscape 4 or IE 5, it will probably still work just fine.